# Why convert Timestamp '2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z' with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, php-5.5

This code :

```
$timestamp = 2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z;
```

How do I separate or convert from the timestamp into a date and time?

example :

```
TimeStamp       2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z
Date            2016-10-06
Jam(GMT +7)     04:55:45
```

Please help to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Use `DateTime::format()` : http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Simply try this:
    `$strtotime = strtotime('2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z');
    $date =  date("Y-m-d", $strtotime);
    $time =  date("H:s:i", $strtotime);
    
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); //set your timezone
    $time_specific_zone =  date("H:s:i", $strtotime);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'); // 2016-10-06T09:50:54.000000
echo $d->format('Y-m-d'); // 2016-10-06

// convert to GMT+7 timezone
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT+7'));
echo $d->format('h:i:s'); //  04:50:54
```

Comment: Hi Galted, Thank you for the help me. The way you are most appropriate for this case.

Comment: what if the results of the date and time we put into mysql database ? '$timestamp = $_GET['timestamp'];
      $date = new DateTime($timestamp);$date->format('Y-m-d');
      $time = new DateTime($timestamp);$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT+7'));$time->format('h:i:s'); '

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this short example:

```
<?php
$datetime = new Datetime('2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z');
var_dump($datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

The output obviously is: `string(19) "2016-10-06 09:50:54"`

Using different format strings you can convert your date time object into whatever representation you want to. `'Y-m-d'` will give the date in international format for example.

Take a look at the great documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$timestamp = "2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z";
$datetime = new Datetime('2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z');
echo "Date".$datetime->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";
echo "Jam".$datetime->format('H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a mystery:

```
<?php
$timestamp = '2016-10-06T09:50:54.000Z';
$dt = new DateTime($timestamp);
var_dump($dt);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));
var_dump($dt);
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-10-06 09:50:54.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-10-06 16:50:54.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(12) "Asia/Jakarta"
}
```

Unlike strings, giving format to a proper date is [trivial](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

I don't know what time zone **Jam** is but I suggest you assign a city so you can account for DST (I've used `Asia/Jakarta` in my sample code, the complete list can be found at [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)). Just relying on a UTC offset like `+7` may make your code unreliable during the summer.